# Drop list if element found in nested list in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Hey I have a huge list coming from server. I am adding some data at top of list. I want to remove data from the list. I have nested list in which I need to find the element in nested list.

```
fun categoriesList() = listOf(
    Categories("21", "physical", listOf(SubTopic("1", "abc"), SubTopic("2", "bjhef"))),
    Categories("2211", "mind", listOf(SubTopic("1", "abc"), SubTopic("2", "bjhef"))),
    Categories("22131", "motorized", listOf(SubTopic("1", "abc"), SubTopic("2", "bjhef"))),
    Categories("2134124", "coordination", listOf(SubTopic("1", "abc"), SubTopic("2", "bjhef"))),
    Categories("211243", "animal-supported", listOf(SubTopic("1", "abc"), SubTopic("2", "bjhef"))),
)
```

**Categories.kt**

```
data class Categories(
    val id: String? = null, val title: String? = null, val subTopic: List<SubTopic>? = null
)
```

**SubTopic.kt**

```
data class SubTopic(
    val id: String? = null, val title: String? = null, var priceId: String? = null
)
```

**main.kt**

```
var categoryList: List<Categories>? = null

fun main() {
    categoryList = categoriesList()
    categoryList?.add(0, Categories("0", "physical-ktm", listOf(SubTopic("1", "vivek"))))
}
```

So I want to find `title = "Vivek"` if that found I want to drop my whole list index 0 element data. **Important** I only need to check element at index 0. I don't want to iterate whole list. If found the data in index 0 drop it otherwise leave it the iteration. So what is efficient way of doing this in kotlin idiomatic way. Can someone guide me. Thanks

UPDATE

```
categoryList?.forEachIndexed { index, data->
    println("$index index -> $data")
}
```

**console**

```
0 index -> Categories(id=0, title=physical-ktm, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=vivek, priceId=null)])
1 index -> Categories(id=21, title=physical, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
2 index -> Categories(id=2211, title=mind, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
3 index -> Categories(id=22131, title=motorized, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
4 index -> Categories(id=2134124, title=coordination, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
5 index -> Categories(id=211243, title=animal-supported, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
```

I only want to search in `0 index` of `Categories` and if `title = "vivek"` is found in `subTopic` then I want to drop `0 index` from `Categories` and stop iteration. If data is not found at all in `subTopic` then I don't won't to iterate whole list of `Categories`.

After @Tenfour04 suggestion I added this code

```
var categoryList: MutableList<Categories>? = null
fun main() {
    categoryList = categoriesList().toMutableList()
    categoryList?.add(0, Categories("0", "physical-ktm", listOf(SubTopic("1", "vivek"))))
    println("After Add")
    categoryList?.forEachIndexed { index, categories ->
        println("$index index -> $categories")
    }

    val matchingIndex = categoryList?.indexOfFirst { it.subTopic?.first()?.title == "vivek" }
    if (matchingIndex != null && matchingIndex >= 0) {
        categoryList = categoryList?.mapIndexed { index, it ->
            if (index == matchingIndex)
                it.copy(subTopic = it.subTopic?.drop(1))
            else
                it
        } as MutableList<Categories>?
    }
    println("After operation")
    categoryList?.forEachIndexed { index, categories ->
        println("$index index -> $categories")
    }
}
```

**Actual Output**

```
After Add
0 index -> Categories(id=0, title=physical-ktm, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=vivek, priceId=null)])
1 index -> Categories(id=21, title=physical, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
2 index -> Categories(id=2211, title=mind, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
3 index -> Categories(id=22131, title=motorized, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
4 index -> Categories(id=2134124, title=coordination, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
5 index -> Categories(id=211243, title=animal-supported, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
After operation
0 index -> Categories(id=0, title=physical-ktm, subTopic=[])
1 index -> Categories(id=21, title=physical, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
2 index -> Categories(id=2211, title=mind, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
3 index -> Categories(id=22131, title=motorized, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
4 index -> Categories(id=2134124, title=coordination, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
5 index -> Categories(id=211243, title=animal-supported, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
```

**Expect Output**

```
After Add
0 index -> Categories(id=0, title=physical-ktm, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=vivek, priceId=null)])
1 index -> Categories(id=21, title=physical, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
2 index -> Categories(id=2211, title=mind, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
3 index -> Categories(id=22131, title=motorized, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
4 index -> Categories(id=2134124, title=coordination, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
5 index -> Categories(id=211243, title=animal-supported, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
After operation
0 index -> Categories(id=21, title=physical, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
1 index -> Categories(id=2211, title=mind, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
2 index -> Categories(id=22131, title=motorized, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
3 index -> Categories(id=2134124, title=coordination, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
4 index -> Categories(id=211243, title=animal-supported, subTopic=[SubTopic(id=1, title=abc, priceId=null), SubTopic(id=2, title=bjhef, priceId=null)])
```

I want to remove whole `Categories`object which is present at index 0.

Comment: Where is the property called _name_? Also no example row carries "Vivek".

Comment: Idiomatic and most-efficient are rarely the same thing in Kotlin. Optimized code will generally be more verbose.

Comment: @lukas.j sorry I mean `title` property. My bad

Comment: I'm unclear about your description of the task. If a certain `title` is found in Category or in one of the SubTopics? And when found does that mean you want to set the `subTopic` List to null or remove that Category from the top level list? And are you saying that once it's found you want to stop searching other Categories?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I only want to search in `0 index` of `Categories` and if `title = "vivek"` is found in `subTopic` then I want to drop `0 index` from `Categories` and stop iteration. If data is not found at all in `subTopic` then I don't won't to iterate whole list of `Categories`.

Comment: so if the first Categories item has "vivek" as a title for one of its subtopics, you want to drop that item? Otherwise you want the full list? `categoryList.run { if (first().subTopic.any { it.title == "vivek" } ) drop(1) else this } ` or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understood description of the task: Find the first (and only first) Categories in `categoriesList` that has a `subList` whose first SubTopic has a `title` of `"vivek"`. If it is found, set `categoriesList` to a new List where the Categories where it was found has been replaced with a new Categories instance whose `subList` has the matched first SubTopic removed.

If prioritizing clarity, I would use `map` even though it will copy the list regardless of whether any Categories are modified. And I'd use a Boolean variable to determine whether the search must continue.

```
var itemFound = false
categoriesList = categoriesList.map {
    if (!itemFound && it.subTopic?.first()?.title == "vivek") {
        itemFound = true
        it.copy(subTopic = it.subTopic?.drop(1))
    } else {
        it
    }
}
```

If prioritizing performance, I would search using `indexOf` so I would only create the new list if necessary. But really, if performance is truly this critical we really should be using mutable collections and data classes. That might not be possible if doing list comparisons, of course.

```
val matchingIndex = categories.indexOfFirst { it.subTopic?.first()?.title == "vivek"}
if (matchingIndex >= 0) {
    categoriesList = categoriesList.mapIndexed { index, it ->
        if (index == matchingIndex)
            it.copy(subTopic = it.subTopic?.drop(1))
        else
            it
    }
}
```

Edit: based on your new comment, I think this is what you are asking for now. Quite a bit simpler.

```
if(categoriesList.first().subTopics.orEmpty().any { it.title == “vivek” }) {
    categoriesList = categoriesList.drop(1)
}
```

Comment: One side point to add...Does `subTopic` really need to be nullable? If we can make it non-nullable and represent 0 subtopics with an empty List, code becomes a little simpler everywhere.

Comment: `subTopic` is nullable it coming from sever. Sometimes data will null.

Comment: Hey @Tenfour04 what does `mapIndexed` do ?

Comment: what is this piece of code doing `  it.copy(subTopic = it.subTopic?.drop(1))` ?

Comment: What do you not understand about these functions? I don’t think I can explain it better than their docs.

Comment: I update my question, can you please check it again.

Comment: Your second code is removing only `subtopic` data but I need to remove whole `category` object which is present at 0 index.

Comment: You said you wanted to “drop 0 index from Categories” not drop the Categories with the match from the Categories List. The Categories item you want to drop isn’t necessarily at the 0 index, is it?

Comment: Ooooooh, I think it makes sense if I swap out the word Categories with `categoriesList` in your earlier comment. You’re talking about the 0 index of `categoriesList` and not of the list inside each Categories item? That’s completely different meaning from what you said in your earlier comment but I think it matches what your saying now.

Comment: Sorry for mis understanding, Now your modified code is working fine. Thanks

Comment: Can you please guide me on this [flow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72588305/11560810)

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand the question correctly, you want to eliminate the first – and only the first – subtopic for each category in *categoriesList* if its *title* is "Vivek":

```
data class SubTopic(
  val id: String? = null,
  val title: String? = null,
  var priceId: String? = null
)

data class Categories(
  val id: String? = null,
  val title: String? = null,
  val subTopic: List<SubTopic>? = null
)

val categoriesList = listOf(
  Categories("21", "physical", listOf(SubTopic("1", "abc"), SubTopic("2", "Vivek"))),
  Categories("2211", "mind", listOf(SubTopic("1", "Vivek"), SubTopic("2", "bjhef"))),
  Categories("22131", "motorized", listOf(SubTopic("1", "abc"), SubTopic("2", "bjhef"))),
  Categories("2134124", "coordination", listOf(SubTopic("1", "Vivek"), SubTopic("2", "Vivek"))),
  Categories("211243", "animal-supported", listOf(SubTopic("1", "abc"), SubTopic("2", "bjhef"))),
)

var categoryList = categoriesList
  .map {
    it.copy(subTopic = it.subTopic
      ?.filterIndexed { index, subTopic -> (index == 0 && subTopic.title != "Vivek") || index > 0 }
    )
  }

categoryList.forEach(::println)
```

Comment: the above code will not search the data in `Categories`if data is not found in the index at 0 in nested list?