# How to use MutableStateFlow to search item in list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, listadapter, kotlin-flow

I am learning kotlin flow in android. I want to basically instant search in my list and filter to show in reyclerview. I searched in google and found this amazing [medium](https://blog.mindorks.com/instant-search-using-kotlin-flow-operators) post. This post is basically search from google. I want to search item in list and show in reyclerview. Can someone guide me how can I start this. I am explanning in more detail

Suppose I have one **SearchBox** and one **Reyclerview** which one item **abc one, abc two, xyz one, xyz two... etc**.

**main image** when all data is combine

[image]

**Scenario 1**

when I start typing in **SearchBox** and enter **small a** or **capital A** I want to show only two item matching in recyclerview, look like this

[image]

**Scenario 2**

when I enter any wrong text in **SearchBox** I want to basically show a text message that not found, look like this

[image]

Any guidance would be great. Thanks

I am adding my piece of code

**ExploreViewModel.kt**

```
class ExploreViewModel(private var list: ArrayList<Category>) : BaseViewModel() {

    val filteredTopics = MutableStateFlow<List<opics>>(emptyList())
    var topicSelected: TopicsArea? = TopicsArea.ALL
        set(value) {
            field = value
            handleTopicSelection(field ?: TopicsArea.ALL)
        }


    private fun handleTopicSelection(value: TopicsArea) {
        if (value == TopicsArea.ALL) {
            filterAllCategories(true)
        } else {
            filteredTopics.value = list.firstOrNull { it.topics != null && it.title == value.title }
                ?.topics?.sortedBy { topic -> topic.title }.orEmpty()
        }
    }

    fun filterAllCategories(isAllCategory: Boolean) {
        if (isAllCategory && topicSelected == TopicsArea.ALL && !isFirstItemIsAllCategory()) {
            list.add(0, code = TopicsArea.ALL.categoryCode))
        } else if (isFirstItemIsAllCategory()) {
            list.removeAt(0)
        }
        filteredTopics.value = list.flatMap { it.topics!! }.distinctBy { topic -> topic.title }.sortedBy { topic -> topic.title }
    }

    private fun isFirstItemIsAllCategory() = list.firstOrNull()?.code == TopicsArea.ALL
}
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_cancel"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/exploreScroll"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/exploreScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchView">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:id="@+id/exploreChips"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:chipSpacingHorizontal="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:singleLine="true"
            app:singleSelection="true" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/exploreList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/exploreScroll" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Category.kt**

```
@Parcelize
data class Category(
    val id: String? = null,
    val title: String? = null,
    val code: String? = null,
    val topics: List<Topics>? = null,
) : Parcelable
```

**Topics.kt**

```
@Parcelize
data class Topics(
    val id: String? = null,
    val title: String? = null
) : Parcelable
```

**Dummy data and coming from server**

```
fun categoriesList() = listOf(
    Categories("21", "physical", listOf(Topics("1", "Abc one"), Topics("2", "Abc Two"))),
    Categories("2211", "mind", listOf(Topics("1", "xyz one"), Topics("2", "xyz two"))),
    Categories("22131", "motorized", listOf(Topics("1", "xyz three"), Topics("2", "xyz four"))),
)
```

> In my view model `list` is holding above dummy data. And In my recyclerview I am passing the whole object and I am doing `flatMap` to combine all data into list. Make sure In recyclerview is using `Topic` and using `title` property. In Image `Abc one`, `Abc two` is holding in `Topic`. Thanks

After @Tenfour04 suggestion I will go to **A2** suggestion because I have already data which converted into flow and passing in my adapter. I am adding my activity code as well.

**ExploreActivity.kt**

```
class ExploreActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val binding by lazy { ExploreLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) }
    val viewModel by viewModel<ExploreViewModel> {
        val list = intent?.getParcelableArrayListExtra(LIST_KEY) ?: emptyList<Category>()
        parametersOf(list)
    }
    var exploreAdapter = ExploreAdapter { topic -> handleNextActivity(topic) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setupView()
    }

    fun setupView() {
        setupSearchView()
        setupFilteredTopic()
        setupExploreAdapter()
    }

    private fun setupFilteredTopic() {
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.CREATED) {
                viewModel.filteredTopics.collect { filteredTopicsList ->
                    exploreAdapter.submitList(filteredTopicsList)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun setupSearchView() {
        binding.searchView.apply {
            setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
                override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?) = false
                override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                    return true
                }
            })
            
        }
    }

    fun setupExploreAdapter() {
        with(binding.exploreList) {
            adapter = exploreAdapter
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

**ExploreViewModel.kt**

```
 val filteredCategories = query
        .debounce(200) // low debounce because we are just filtering local data
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .combine(filteredTopics) { queryText, categoriesList ->
            val criteria = queryText.lowercase()
            if (criteria.isEmpty()) {
                    return@combine filteredTopics 
            } else {
                categoriesList.filter { category -> category.title?.lowercase()?.let { criteria.contains(it) } == true }
            }
        }
```

I am getting error when I set in adapter

fixed

**filteredTopics.value**

[image]

Comment: I just made sort-of the same thing, but not using flow. I just pass an `ArrayList` to the `reyclerview` that matches with my search. But that is maybe not the solution you are looking for

Comment: Yeah, I am not looking for `ArrayList`. Flow is more powerful than list. That's why I want to learn this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you linked has a Flow produced by the SearchView. If you want to keep the search functionality in your ViewModel, you can put a MutableStateFlow in your ViewModel that will be updated by the SearchView indirectly. You can expose a property for updating the query.

There are two different ways this could be done, depending on whether you (A) already have a complete list of your data that you want to query quickly or (B) you want to query a server or your database every time your query text changes.

And then even (A) can be broken up into: (A1) you have a static plain old List, or (A2) your source List comes from a Flow, such as a returned Room flow that is not based on query parameters.

All code below is in the ViewModel class.

**A1:**

```
private val allCategories = categoriesList()
private val query = MutableStateFlow("")

// You should add an OnQueryTextListener on your SearchView that
// sets this property in the ViewModel
var queryText: String
    get() = query.value
    set(value) { query.value = value }

// This is the flow that should be observed for the updated list that 
// can be passed to the RecyclerView.Adapter.
val filteredCategories = query
    .debounce(200) // low debounce because we are just filtering local data
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .map { 
        val criteria = it.lowercase()
        allCategories.filter { category -> criteria in category.title.lowercase }
    }
```

**A2:**

In this example I put a simple placeholder flow for the upstream server query. This could be any flow.

```
private val allCategories = flow {
    categoriesList()
}
private val query = MutableStateFlow("")

// You should add an OnQueryTextListener on your SearchView that
// sets this property in the ViewModel
var queryText: String
    get() = query.value
    set(value) { query.value = value }

// This is the flow that should be observed for the updated list that 
// can be passed to the RecyclerView.Adapter.
val filteredCategories = query
    .debounce(200) // low debounce because we are just filtering local data
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .combine(allCategories) { queryText, categoriesList ->
        val criteria = queryText.lowercase()
        categoriesList.filter { category -> criteria in category.title.lowercase }
    }
```

**B**

```
private val query = MutableStateFlow("")

// You should add an OnQueryTextListener on your SearchView that
// sets this property in the ViewModel
var queryText: String
    get() = query.value
    set(value) { query.value = value }

// This is the flow that should be observed for the updated list that 
// can be passed to the RecyclerView.Adapter.
val filteredCategories = query
    .debounce(500) // maybe bigger to avoid too many queries
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .map { 
        val criteria = it.lowercase()
        categoriesList(criteria) // up to you to implement this depending on source
    }
```

Comment: Hey @Tenfour04 thanks for million for helping me. I have some doubt. I added my activity code in my question. Your **A2** suggestion is fitting in my scenario. I have `filteredTopics` which is mutableStateFlow in my **viewmodel**. I am using`filteredTopics` to setup my initial adapter data.  In your **A2** example you use `allCategories` which is private and  you are suggestion to use `filteredCategories` property to adapter so how can I add initial data to adapter? If you don't understand please refer to my main image in question.

Comment: I will explain in more detail. When activity start, I am showing `searchview`, `RV` with data, which I did successfully with using `filteredTopics` property. So you are suggestion to use `filteredCategories` to set in my adpater. Suppose I did that. But when my start my activity my `RV` data is empty because my initial data is in `filteredCategories` property. Did you get it now what I am getting problem now?

Comment: I think I messed it up so it was dropping values. See the modified version. I don't have time to test it, so hopefully that works.

Comment: Hey @Tenfour04 the changes you did. In your suggestion how `filteredCategories` knows where is the source of all data?

Comment: Oops again. I missed including that in the `combine` call.

Comment: One question if I didn't have any text in `query` than `filteredCategories` have whole data ?

Comment: I replace your `combine(allCategories)` with mine `combine(filteredTopics)` my initial load data is not working. My `RV` showing empty when initial screen start.

Comment: Actually I didn’t think about what happens when you use `”” in`. I don’t know if that always returns true or false. If it returns false, you will of course need to use if/else and return the whole list when the query test is empty.

Comment: I update my question in **UPDATE 2** section. I tried some code, but I am getting error when I am passing the `filteredCategories` in my adapter. Can you guide me on that and `filteredCategories` code is correct ? Thanks

Comment: You are returning `filteredTopics` instead of `categoriesList` when your query is empty. I think you meant to put `categoriesList`? `filteredTopics` could be a Flow or something else, which would cause your final flow type to be Any (the common supertype of a List and a Flow) and kind of useless. Also, the behave better for search, you should probably make it `val criteria = it.trim().lowercase()` so trailing spaces are ignored.

Comment: Do you have any ide how can I solve this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72609914/11560810)